# Image button alters position on hover

Tags: javascript, css, image

There was a great effect I've seen back in the day and now I can't find anything about it.

The concept is that there is an image with both the normal and onHover appearance combined into one image. On hover the image would shift and show the onHover appearance.

Here's a visual example:

[image]

I'm pretty sure it has this sort of code involved:

```
<img id="button" src="img.png" width="100" height="50">

onHover:
document.getElementById("button").top = "-50";
```

Comment: yea I didn't know the name. I thought it was javascript trick, not css :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
#button {
    background-image:url('img.png');
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#button:hover {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}
```

Comment: It's common practice for sprites. I use it all the time :)

Comment: Has he tried it? It's totally a web standard now. In fact, you'd be crazy to do it any other way unless your buttons were animated

Comment: LOL gosh, I couldn't find it anywhere so I was just making sure...I'm going to try it right now.

Comment: Alright I'm accepting this answer because it was indeed what I was looking for but I'm editing the original post so it properly reflects how it would work with my image (vertically re-positioned). THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div></div>​
```

CSS:

```
<style>
div{
    width:98px;
    height:45px;
    /*border:1px solid red;*/
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxznh.png');
    background-position: -83px -123px;
}
div:hover {
    background-position: -83px -177px;
}
​</style>
```

[Here is a demo for it](http://jsfiddle.net/F8jCE/)